# dynamically change modal-dialog css style

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I am trying to change already predefined css style of "modal-dialog"/"modal-dialog-content" dynamically before it's appearance i.e

```
.modal-dialog-content {
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:visible; 
transform: scale(1);
}
```

I was trying

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-dialog-content')[0].style.transform ='scale('+ 0.5 +')';
or    
    document.querySelector('.modal-dialog-content').style.transform='scale('+ 0.5 +')';
```

However upon appearance it still has predefined "scale(1)"

Below FF inspector's data of actual css and scripts before and after script execution. Before execution:

```
   .vjs-modal-dialog .vjs-modal-dialog-content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible; 
    transform: scale(1);
    }
```

After execution:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('vjs-modal-dialog-content')[0].style.transform ='scale('+ 0.5 +')';
 or    
 document.querySelector('.vjs-modal-dialog-content').style.transform='scale('+ 0.5 +')';
```

FF inspector's data sill shows:

```
   .vjs-modal-dialog .vjs-modal-dialog-content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible; 
    transform: scale(1);
    }
```

Comment: this works fine

Comment: It doesn't for me. I updated post with actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved (kind of) by loop through array:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vjs-modal-dialog-content');
```

and change style in every instance i.e.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.vjs-modal-dialog-content');
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.transform ='scale('+ 0.5 +')';}
```

probably not the best solution, however...